# Fix the vertical alignment inside Algorithm Pseudocode

Tags: vertical-alignment, algorithms, algpseudocode

I am new to Latex and I am writing the pseudocode of an algorithm in Latex. For each step of the algorithm I want to provide a description of that step. I use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsopn,amscd,amsthm,bbm,dsfont,mathtools, 
float, algorithm, algpseudocode, tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Initialize: $\textit{est} \gets 0$
\hspace{39mm}Initialize MC estimate at 0
\State \hspace{15mm}
$\textit{se} \gets 0$
 \hspace{40mm}Initialize standard error at 0

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image: scheef]

I want the description to be aligned perfectly. Now I am using \hspace for the whitespace, but I cannot get the different lines to line up. Can someone help me with the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Use `\makebox[<width>][<alignment>]{..}` for both lines before the description. Then, your description will begin after exactly that `width` you specified on the two lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsopn,amscd,amsthm,bbm,dsfont,mathtools, 
float, algorithm, algpseudocode, tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Awesome Algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State \makebox[6cm][l]{Initialize: $\textit{est} \gets 0$}                     Initialize MC estimate at 0
  \State \makebox[6cm][l]{\phantom{Initialize: $\textit{t}$}$\textit{se}\gets0$}  Initialize standard error at 0
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```